# Customize Update password page in AD FS 3.0

Tags: iis, adfs, windows-server, adfs3.0

I need to add a new textbox field in the update password page in ad fs 3.0, hovewer I can not find any solutions how to do. I found a few articles about the sign in page. It is possible to do ?

I will be appreciated for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's tons of examples here - [ADFS : Continuing the Login and Home Realm Discovery (HRD) and Change Password customisation adventure](https://nzpcmad.blogspot.co.nz/2017/06/adfs-continuing-login-and-home-realm.html).

Essentially, you do this with onload.js.